# Write into CSV only if row does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am saving an array into a csv file, using this code:

```
def save_annotations(**kwargs):

    ann = request.get_json()
    print(ann)
    filename = ann[3].split('.')[0]
    run_id = ann[4]
    run_number = ann[4].split('/')[0]
    exp_id = ann[4].split('/')[1]
    ann_type = ann[2]

    if ann_type == 'wrongDetection':
        with open(f"/code/data/mlruns/{run_number}/{exp_id}/wrong_annotations_{filename}_{run_id.replace('/', '_')}.csv",'a') as w_ann:
            writer = csv.writer(w_ann, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(ann[0:2]) 
        w_ann.close()
    else:
        with open(f"/code/data/mlruns/{run_number}/{exp_id}/new_detections_{filename}_{run_id.replace('/', '_')}.csv",'a') as w_ann:
            writer = csv.writer(w_ann, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(ann[0:2]) 
        w_ann.close()
```

However, I don't want repeated rows in my csv file. I only want to write to csv if `ann[0]` and `ann[1]` are not in the csv already.

What would be the best approach to do this?

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to collect the already existing values in a set, and check new values to see if they are in the set before processing.  You would need a set for each csv file.

For example:

```
def build_set(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        # Skip header row, if necessary
        next(reader)
        return {tuple(row[0:2]) for row in reader}
```

Then in your function you could do:

```
if tuple(ann[0:2]) in set_for_this_file:
    continue
set_for_this_file.add(tuple(ann[0:2]))
# write data to file
```

Building the sets would require reading through all the csv files each time the program is executed, which might be inefficient if the files were large and/or numerous.

A more efficient approach might be to store the data in a database table, with columns for `ann[0]`, `ann[1]`, `anntype`, `exp_id`, `run_mumber` and `run_id`.  Add a unique constraint over these columns and you would have the same functionality.